# How can I check the HTTP response from inside a MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EditViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I know I can check the viewModel object when debugging but how can I get the actual HTTP response from within the controller at the "..." point?

Also how can I see the data that gets bound to the viewModel (without looking at the viewModel). Where's that data stored in the Response object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) as a parameter to your POST action method, MVC will populate it with the posted form data. Or through the [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.form.aspx) property of the Request

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EditViewModel viewModel, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var name = formCollection["name"];

    var email = Request.Form["email"];
}
```

But modifying it inside the controller violates the whole "MVC" pattern.

Comment: I checked and I cannot see the response data that should be sent to the viewModel. I realize this is outside of the scope of the first question but do you know where this data is kept within the response object?

Comment: @Melissa What do you mean by **response data that should be sent to the viewModel**?

Comment: I mean the data coming back from the form. The actual text the user may have entered when filling out an input box.

Comment: @Melissa That gave whole new meaning to what you asked :) See my edited answer.